# Filter unique & duplicate objects in array using underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of objects:

```
data = [{"origin":"SJU","dest":"JFK","rank":48},{"origin":"JFK","dest":"SJU","rank":21},{"origin":"IAD","dest":"LAX","rank":31},{"origin":"LAS","dest":"SJU","rank":21}]
```

I am trying to extract all duplicates & unique objects BY "origin" & "dest". So that these 2 are the same, ignoring the rank key

- `{origin:'JFK',dest:'SJU',rank:21}`
- `{"origin":"SJU","dest":"JFK","rank":48}`

Basically I want 2 seperate arrays:

`duplicates=[{"origin":"SJU","dest":"JFK","rank":48},{"origin":"JFK","dest":"SJU","rank":21}]`

`unique = [{"origin":"IAD","dest":"LAX","rank":31},{"origin":"LAS","dest":"SJU","rank":21}]`

using underscore, I was able to throw something like this together. But It seems inefficient and only returns an array of duplicates:

```
duplicates = _.chain(data).map(function (d) {
    var ar = [d.origin, d.dest];
    return ar.sort();
}).sortBy(function (d) {
    return d
}).groupBy(function (d) {return d}).map(function (d) {
    if (d.length > 1) {
        return d[0]
    }
}).compact().value()
single = _.chain(data).map(function (d) {
    var ar = [d.origin, d.dest];
    return ar.sort();
}).sortBy(function (d) {
    return d
}).groupBy(function (d) {
    return d
}).map(function (d) {
    if (d.length == 1) {
        return d[0]
    }
}).compact().value()
```

I can't help but feel there is a much easier way to get this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to introduce a temporary variable to hold the groups:

```
var data = [{"origin":"SJU","dest":"JFK","rank":48},{"origin":"JFK","dest":"SJU","rank":21},{"origin":"IAD","dest":"LAX","rank":31},{"origin":"LAS","dest":"SJU","rank":21}]

var groups = _.groupBy(data, function(item) {
  return [item.origin, item.dest].sort();
});
```

Then:

```
var duplicates = [],
singles = [];

_.each(groups, function(group) {
  if (group.length > 1) {
    duplicates.push.apply(duplicates, group);
  } else {
    singles.push(group[0]);
  }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/muwubeda/2/watch?js,console)

Comment: Ahhhh - I am not sure about the [0] at the end of your code. But from this, I was able to get what I needed. Much simpler. Thanks!:  `singles = _.chain(groups).filter(function(group) {
  return group.length == 1;
}).flatten().value()` and `duplicates = _.chain(groups).filter(function(group) {
  return group.length > 1;
}).flatten().value()`

Comment: @user3760167 Yeah, I was struggling with Underscore there for a bit :) it should return the correct values now.

Comment: @user3760167 It would be more efficient to avoid filtering twice and there's no need for it. Just build `dupes` and `uniques` in a single run.

Comment: thanks! I didn't think about doing it without chaining... I think the final thing missing is returning the single array of duplicates: `duplicates = _.flatten(_.filter(groups, function(group) {
  return group.length > 1;
}).map(function(item) { 
  return item;
}));`

Comment: @Jack That's cool, since when can we notify more than a single user like this /cc:@user3760167 ? Anyway, the algo is better that way ;)

Comment: @plalx I don't think the notification is sent to two people actually, but I'm used to writing it that way in the hopes they will read the comments again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code. However I got the problem.

The way I see it is 2 steps:

- identify duplicates and push them in an array duplicates
- create the uniquearray by copying the inital array and remove all the elements that match duplicates array.

Maybe it has lower performance but it could be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the algorithm using plain javascript. It is probably not the most efficient one if you  will have thousands of records, but it get's the job done.

```
var data = [
    {"origin": "SJU", "dest": "JFK", "rank":48},
    {"origin": "JFK", "dest": "SJU", "rank":21},
    {"origin": "IAD", "dest": "LAX", "rank":31},
    {"origin": "LAS", "dest": "SJU", "rank":21}
];

var uniques = [];
var doubles = [];

var i, j, l = data.length, origin, dest, foundDouble;

for ( i = 0; i < l; i += 1 ) {
    origin = data[i].origin;
    dest = data[i].dest;
    foundDouble = false;

    for ( j = 0; j < l; j += 1 ) {
        //skip the same row
        if ( i == j ) {
            continue;
        }

        if ( (data[j].origin == origin || data[j].origin == dest) && (data[j].dest == origin || data[j].dest == dest) ) {
            doubles.push( data[i] );
            foundDouble = true;
        }
    }

    if ( !foundDouble ) {
        uniques.push( data[i] );
    }
}

console.log( 'Uniques', uniques );
console.log( 'Doubles', doubles );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but here's one. I never used underscore, but the algorithm is pretty straight forward and you should be able to convert it easily.

```
var voyages = [{"origin":"SJU","dest":"JFK","rank":48},{"origin":"JFK","dest":"SJU","rank":21},{"origin":"IAD","dest":"LAX","rank":31},{"origin":"LAS","dest":"SJU","rank":21}],
    dupes = [],
    uniques = [],
    countMap = new Map(), //Map is from Harmony, but you can use a plain object
    voyageKeyOf = function (voyage) { return [voyage.origin, voyage.dest].sort().join(''); },
    uniques;

//Create a map that stores how many times every voyage keys were seen
voyages.forEach(function (voyage) {
    var key = voyageKeyOf(voyage),
        hasCount = countMap.get(key);

    if (!hasCount) countMap.set(key, 1);
    else {
        let count = countMap.get(key);
        countMap.set(key, ++count);
    }
});

voyages.forEach(function (voyage) {
    var key = voyageKeyOf(voyage),
        isUnique = countMap.get(key) == 1;

    if (isUnique) uniques.push(voyage)
    else dupes.push(voyage);
});


console.log('uniques', uniques);
console.log('dupes', dupes);
```

Comment: Where does `Map` come from?

Comment: @Jack https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Map It's from Harmony. I added a note ;)

Comment: The reason people use Underscore is so that they don't have to worry about different browser versions ...

Comment: @Jack Yes and underscore is a great abstraction. I am not suggesting to use this code, I said it could easily be ported to underscore, but I never used it so it would take more time for me to port it compared to someone who knows it already.

Comment: I've never used Underscore either ;-)

Comment: @Jack Well I guess I was lazier than you hehe =P