# ramda.js: obtain a set of duplicates from an array of objects using specific properties

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Given this array, containing javascript objects (json):
Each object has a `b`property, and a `u` property,

*(each contains additional properties I am not concerned with for this exercise).*

```
[
    { "b": "A", "u": "F", ... },
    { "b": "M", "u": "T", ... },
    { "b": "A", "u": "F", ... },
    { "b": "M", "u": "T", ... },
    { "b": "M", "u": "T", ... },
    { "b": "X", "u": "Y", ... },
    { "b": "X", "u": "G", ... },
]
```

I would like to use ramda to find a set of all the duplicates.
The result should look something like this.

```
[ 
    { "b": "A", "u":"F" },
    { "b": "M", "u":"T" } 
]
```

These two entries have duplicates they are repeated 2 and 3 times in the original list respectively.

**edit**

I have found a solution using [underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327912/filter-unique-duplicate-objects-in-array-using-underscore), that keeps the original array elements, and splits them perfectly into singles and duplicates. I prefer ramda.js, and underscore doesn't just give a set of duplicates - as per the question, so I am leaving the question open until someone can answer using ramda. I am moving on with underscore until the question is answered.

I have a [repl](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?var%20data%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22A%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22F%22%2C%20%22DONTCARE%22%3A%20%22A%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22M%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22T%22%2C%20%22DONTCARE%22%3A%20%22B%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22A%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22F%22%2C%20%22X%22%3A%20%22M%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22M%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22T%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22M%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22T%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22X%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22Y%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22X%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22G%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%5D%0A%0Avar%20picked%20%3D%20R.map%28R.pick%28%5B%22b%22%2C%20%22u%22%5D%29%29%28data%29%3B%0Avar%20unique%20%3D%20R.uniqWith%28R.equals%29%28picked%29%3B%0Aunique%3B) that finds the unique values... as a start...

Comment: Do you want complete duplicates or only those that match on `b` and `u`?

Comment: no, only the matching fields, "b" and "u" - though for interest - it would be nice to know. I suspect that R.equals might cater for all being equal.

Comment: I have spent a whole lot more time trying to resolve this using R.head, and R.tail - have come to the conclusion that this is a m*** of a tricksy question... Trying to somehow iterate over the unique list, and remove one match from the data for each match in unique seems like the right approach... but I haven't managed to get the composition correct yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems overcomplicated and unlikely to be performant, but one options would be this:

```
const foo = pipe(
  project(['b', 'u']),
  reduce(
    ({results, foundOnce}, item) => contains(item, results)
      ? {results, foundOnce}
      : contains(item, foundOnce)
        ? {results: append(item, results), foundOnce}
        : {results, foundOnce: append(item, foundOnce)},
    {results: [], foundOnce: []}
  ), 
  prop('results')
)

foo(xs); //=> [{b: 'A', u: 'F'}, {b: 'M', u: 'T'}]
```

Perhaps this version is easier to understand, but it takes an extra iteration through the data:

```
const foo = pipe(
  project(['b', 'u']),
  reduce(
    ({results, foundOnce}, item) => contains(item, foundOnce)
        ? {results: append(item, results), foundOnce}
        : {results, foundOnce: append(item, foundOnce)},
    {results: [], foundOnce: []}
  ),
  prop('results'),
  uniq
)
```

[repl here](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?var%20data%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22A%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22F%22%2C%20%22DONTCARE%22%3A%20%22A%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22M%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22T%22%2C%20%22DONTCARE%22%3A%20%22B%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22A%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22F%22%2C%20%22X%22%3A%20%22M%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22M%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22T%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22M%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22T%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22X%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22Y%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22X%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22G%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20foo%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20project%28%5B%27b%27%2C%20%27u%27%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20reduce%28%0A%20%20%20%20%28%7Bresults%2C%20foundOnce%7D%2C%20item%29%20%3D%3E%20contains%28item%2C%20foundOnce%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20%7Bresults%3A%20append%28item%2C%20results%29%2C%20foundOnce%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20%7Bresults%2C%20foundOnce%3A%20append%28item%2C%20foundOnce%29%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bresults%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%20foundOnce%3A%20%5B%5D%7D%0A%20%20%29%2C%0A%20%20prop%28%27results%27%29%2C%0A%20%20uniq%0A%29%3B%0A%0Afoo%28data%29%3B)

Comment: Sorry but I can't check your results right now - I've been out celebrating - but I have to completely admire the kind of twisted mind that came up with this... I'll check it in the morning and upvote as best I can. You rock! - FYI I am more interested in the solution than performance - the list of matches is very short.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about looping over your data multiple times, you could something like this:

- Create partial copies that contain only the relevant props, using `pick` (your own idea)
- use `groupBy` with a `hash` function to group similar objects. ([Alternatively](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?var%20data%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22A%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22F%22%2C%20%22DONTCARE%22%3A%20%22A%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22M%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22T%22%2C%20%22DONTCARE%22%3A%20%22B%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22A%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22F%22%2C%20%22X%22%3A%20%22M%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22M%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22T%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22M%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22T%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22X%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22G%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22X%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22Y%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22X%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22G%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20containsMoreThanOne%20%3D%20compose%28lt%281%29%2C%20length%29%3B%0Aconst%20hash%20%3D%20JSON.stringify%3B%0A%0Aconst%20getDups%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20map%28pick%28%5B%22b%22%2C%20%22u%22%5D%29%29%2C%0A%20%20sortWith%28%5Bdescend%28prop%28%22b%22%29%29%2C%20descend%28prop%28%22u%22%29%29%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20groupWith%28equals%29%2C%0A%20%20filter%28containsMoreThanOne%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28head%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0AgetDups%28data%29%3B%0A): `sort` first and use `groupWith(equals)`)
- Get the grouped arrays using `values`
- Filter out arrays with only 1 item (those are not duped...) using `filter`
- Map over the results and return the first element of each array using `map(head)`

In code:

```
const containsMoreThanOne = compose(lt(1), length);
const hash = JSON.stringify; // Naive.. watch out for key-order!

const getDups = pipe(
  map(pick(["b", "u"])),
  groupBy(hash),
  values,
  filter(containsMoreThanOne),
  map(head)
);

getDups(data);
```

Working demo in [Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?var%20data%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22A%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22F%22%2C%20%22DONTCARE%22%3A%20%22A%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22M%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22T%22%2C%20%22DONTCARE%22%3A%20%22B%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22A%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22F%22%2C%20%22X%22%3A%20%22M%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22M%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22T%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22M%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22T%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22X%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22G%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22X%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22Y%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22X%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22G%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20containsMoreThanOne%20%3D%20compose%28lt%281%29%2C%20length%29%3B%0Aconst%20hash%20%3D%20JSON.stringify%3B%0A%0Aconst%20getDups%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20map%28pick%28%5B%22b%22%2C%20%22u%22%5D%29%29%2C%0A%20%20groupBy%28hash%29%2C%0A%20%20values%2C%0A%20%20filter%28containsMoreThanOne%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28head%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0AgetDups%28data%29%3B%0A).

A more hybrid approach would be to cramp all this logic in one reducer, but it looks kind of messy to me...

```
const clean = pick(["b", "u"]);
const hash = JSON.stringify;
const dupReducer = hash => (acc, o) => {
    const h = hash(o);
    // Mutate internal state
    acc.done[h] = (acc.done[h] || 0) + 1;
    if (acc.done[h] === 2) acc.result.push(o);

    return acc;
  };


const getDups = (clean, hash, data) =>
  reduce(dupReducer(hash), { result: [], done: { } }, map(clean, data)).result;

getDups(clean, hash, data);
```

[REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?var%20data%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22A%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22F%22%2C%20%22DONTCARE%22%3A%20%22A%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22M%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22T%22%2C%20%22DONTCARE%22%3A%20%22B%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22A%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22F%22%2C%20%22X%22%3A%20%22M%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22M%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22T%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22M%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22T%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22X%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22G%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22X%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22Y%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22b%22%3A%20%22X%22%2C%20%22u%22%3A%20%22G%22%2C%20ELSE%3A%22MMH%22%20%7D%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20clean%20%3D%20pick%28%5B%22b%22%2C%20%22u%22%5D%29%3B%0Aconst%20hash%20%3D%20JSON.stringify%3B%0Aconst%20dupReducer%20%3D%20hash%20%3D%3E%20%28acc%2C%20o%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20h%20%3D%20hash%28o%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Mutate%20internal%20state%0A%20%20%20%20acc.done%5Bh%5D%20%3D%20%28acc.done%5Bh%5D%20%7C%7C%200%29%20%2B%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28acc.done%5Bh%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%202%29%20acc.result.push%28o%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20return%20acc%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Aconst%20getDups%20%3D%20%28clean%2C%20hash%2C%20data%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20reduce%28dupReducer%28hash%29%2C%20%7B%20result%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%20done%3A%20%7B%20%7D%20%7D%2C%20map%28clean%2C%20data%29%29.result%3B%0A%0AgetDups%28clean%2C%20hash%2C%20data%29%3B%0A)

Answer (score 0):

```
  const arr = [];
  const duplicates = [];
  const values1 =  [
  { b: 'A', u: 'F', a: 'q' },
  { b: 'M', u: 'T', a: 'q' },
  { b: 'A', u: 'F', a: 'q' },
  { b: 'M', u: 'T', a: 'q' },
  { b: 'M', u: 'T', a: 'q' },
  { b: 'X', u: 'Y', a: 'q' },
  { b: 'X', u: 'G', a: 'q' },
 ];
 values1.forEach(eachValue => {
 arr.push(values(pick(['b', 'u'], eachValue)));
 });
 arr.forEach(fish => {
 if ( indexOf(fish, arr) !== lastIndexOf(fish, arr) ) {
   duplicates.push(zipObj(['b', 'u'], fish));
 }
});

[blog]: https://ramdafunctionsexamples.com/ "click here for updates"

<https://ramdafunctionsexamples.com/>?
```

Answer (score -1):

Not an expert with Ramda JS but I think the following should work :

```
var p = [
    { "b": "A", "u": "F" },
    { "b": "A", "u": "F" },
    { "b": "A", "u": "F" },
    { "b": "A", "u": "F" },
    { "b": "A", "u": "F" },
    { "b": "M", "u": "T" }
];
var dupl = n => n > 1;
R.compose(
    R.map(JSON.parse),
    R.keys,
    R.filter(dupl),
    R.countBy(String),
    R.map(JSON.stringify)
)(p)
```

Please let me know if it does.

Comment: updated answer to call the right R method (`uniqBy`)

Comment: I believe the question is asking to find the set of elements that have a duplicate.

Comment: @StevenGoodman indeed . Let me fix the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @82Tuskers nice try, but I only want to compare on "b" and "u", as I mentioned, there are other fields.

Comment: If you only want to compare on these fields, and also only want to return these ones, then you could fix this by starting the pipeline with `project(['b', 'u'])`.

I'm not fond of the `JSON.parse`/`JSON.stringify` solution, though.  They may not be appropriate to your data.

Comment: I spent an hour trying with R.pick, and got close, but I have to move on, I have also edited the question for clarity.